# Flutter Google Maps how to disable marker position animation/interpolation

Tags: flutter, google-maps

By updating the marker's position, I can move the marker on the map, however, the movement looks awkward in my case as I want it to move along with the polyline but the marker's position interpolation makes it moves behind the polyline, so I wonder if there a way to disable it? Like immediately changing the position without any animation?